# Rendering a page with html2canvas as if the browser window had a different size

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to create a client-side PDF rendering of a page. The generated PDF should preserve CSS styles.

To that end, I'm using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation) through [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF):

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var html2canvasOpts =  { 
        background: '#ffffff'
    }
doc.addHTML($('#mytargetelement')[0], html2canvasOpts, function () {
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
});
```

It's working well. However, I have noticed that the layout of the elements in the generated PDF mirrors that of the original page, and resizing the browser window will result in a different-looking PDF.

For the sake of uniformity, I'm interested in rendering the PDF as if the browser window had a predetermined standard size set by me, instead of the actual size it may have in the browser (I don't want to force a resize of the actual browser window). Is that possible with `html2canvas`? I have experimented with configuration options like `width`, `height`, `windowWidth` and `windowHeight`, but they don't seem to do what I want.

Alternatively, is there other library or technique that can be used for this?

Comment: I have the exact problem. the windowWidth doesn't work es expected. in my case, i have a website using bootstrap and i want to use html2canvas to get the screenshot when the webpage is in mobile, so i set {windowWidth: 767}, but the webpage captured turns out to be malformed.

Comment: were you able to find a way to solve this?

Comment: @el-aasi No, I wasn't.